# Javascript: how to convert datetime from yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss to m/d/yyyy h:mm am/pm

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have an HTML form that I have put together that takes the input from the user and creates an Email to be sent off to a distro list. I am having an issue with getting the date from the form to convert nicely to a different format. The current output shows and "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM" and I am looking to have it show "MM/DD/YYYY H:MM AM/PM"

Here is the line of Codes in HTML

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Event Start:</div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="cell"><input type="datetime-local" id="start_dt" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell" style="text-align: center;"><button type="submit" style="width: 90%;" class="SubmitButton" onClick="createEmail();">Generate Email</button></div>
</div>
                
<script src="JS\testemail.js"></script>

</body>
```

And hers is my JavaScript

```
function createEmail() { 

let f = document.getElementById("start_dt").value.replace("T", " ");

let m_to = "Distro_List"
let m_cc = "CC_List"


document.location.href = "mailto:" + encodeURIComponent(m_to) + "?cc=" + encodeURIComponent(m_cc)
+ " &subject=Storm Mode"
+ " "
+ "&body=" 
+ "%0D%0A%0D%0A"
+ "Event Start: " + encodeURIComponent(f) + "%0D%0A"
        }
```

I have tried a few of the solutions found on SO using Librarys with `momement.js`, but I can not download this onto my work machine. Here is the solution from SO that I tried to implement [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)
and I tried using this site https://www.valentinog.com/blog/datetime/

I know my lack of knowledge on HTML and JS has me stumped on what I should do next. Any direction or pointers to help me on my way will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for the messy code, I am still learning

Comment: This is basically the same as the question you've linked to, [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date). There are 53 answers to that question, and the accepted answer has a detailed explanation of how to do format a date. Perhaps you can explain more about what you tried from those answers so that we don't end up writing the same answers over again.

Comment: I believe I am having an issue with getting the input from the form to be converted. Every example has var d = new date.  I have tried `let f = document.getElementById("start_dt").value` and then converting from there but nothing happens

Comment: Try `let d = new Date(f);` and go from there (without the `replace`).

Comment: UGH...I thought I tried that. Thank you.  I will continue to look through the solutions to get the time formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in the browser, you can avoid importing giant libraries like `moment.js` by using the native [`Intl.DateTimeFormat` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat). The following options look to be pretty close to what you want:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  hour12: true,
})

const iStillDontUnderstandWhyAnyoneThoughtMonthDayYearWasAGoodIdeaForADateFormatButWhatDoIKnow
  = formatter.format(new Date()) // "08/13/2020, 4:46 PM"
```

Optionally, you could also get rid of the comma with

```js
iStillDontUnderstandWhyAnyoneThoughtMonthDayYearWasAGoodIdeaForADateFormatButWhatDoIKnow
  .replace(',', '') // "08/13/2020 4:52 PM"
```

Comment: Thank you, this does everything I need it to. and with the help from Hectic Monkey, I was able to integrate it in with no issues. I agree with the variable name